What kind of functions have radial Fourier series coefficients?
Suppose $f : \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$ and has Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(j) = (2\pi)^{-d}\int_{\mathbb{T}^d}f(\theta)e^{-ij^T\theta}$. If $\hat{f}(j) = \hat{f}(j')$ whenever $\|j\|^2 = \|j'\|^2$, what can we say about $f$?. We can conclude that if $R$ is any orthogonal matrix mapping $\mathbb{Z}^d$ into $\mathbb{Z}^d$, then $f(\theta) = f(R\theta)$. But this isn't sufficient as this only implies $\hat{f}$ is invariant under negation of coordinates and permutation of coordinates, so we can't deduce $\hat{f}(3, 4) = \hat{f}(5, 0)$.

@Masacroso I added the assumption that $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d)$, as smoothness doesn't matter for my question. The property $f \circ T = f$ for all linear isometries $T$ that fix $\mathbb{Z}^d$ does not imply that $\hat{f}$ is radial. It only implies $\hat{f}(j)$ is invariant under permutation of the arguments and negation of any argument.
